# Unable to login into Flipkart using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to login into flipkart and add a product to my cart. But I am unable to login into the site (programatically).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import datetime
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
flipkart_url='https://www.flipkart.com/account/login?from=header'
driver.get(flipkart_url)
time.sleep(1)
elem_email = driver.find_element_by_id("login_email_id1")
yourusername="aa@ccc.com"
elem_email.send_keys(yourusername)
time.sleep(1)


password="abcdef"
elem_password = driver.find_element_by_id("login_password1")
elem_password.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
elem_password.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(1)
actions=ActionChains(driver)

actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('c').perform()
time.sleep(1)
actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('v').perform()


elem_submit=driver.find_element_by_id('login-cta')

actions.click(elem_submit)



elem_password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This code is not displaying any errors but when I look at the top right corner, my logged in user name is not being displayed

Comment: I think there is a `wait_for_element` or something that waits till that element is loaded that you will need to use

Comment: I am using ctrl+c and ctrl+v just to simulate some key strokes

Comment: You enter username:password, then you press Tab, Ctrl-C, and Ctrl-V, Return inside of the password field. Which of those actually performs the login action?!?! How about something like `driver.find_element_by_tagname('form').submit()`? Or even `driver.find_element_by_id('login-cta').click()`?